# Execution failed for task ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:parseDebugLocalResources'

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I am building an app in Flutter and it runs perfectly on iOS but when I try and run it on Android, both on an emulator and on a real device, I get the error below. Please note that I am not using the package flutter_keyboard_visibility in my app so I have no idea where it is coming from. I searched my code for any mention of flutter_keyboard_visibility and it only appears in the ‎rides2u/ios/Podfile.lock file:

- flutter_keyboard_visibility (0.0.1):

  - Flutter
- flutter_image_compress_common (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_image_compress_common/ios`)
- flutter_keyboard_visibility (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_keyboard_visibility/ios`)
- geolocator_apple (from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`)

flutter_keyboard_visibility:
:path: ".symlinks/plugins/flutter_keyboard_visibility/ios"

flutter_keyboard_visibility: 0339d06371254c3eb25eeb90ba8d17dca8f9c069

**Error:**
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform:

/Users/ellenjoyce/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar.

> 

/Users/ellenjoyce/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at

https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried the following things:

- running it in Android Studio rather than VSCode
- changing the ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0’
- running flutter clean
- running it on phone and emulator
- setting the minSdkVersion between 20 and 30
- changing the targetSdkVersion from flutter.targetSdkVersion to 30-33
- deleting `android/.gradle` and then run the app in debug mode
- changing the SDK to Android API 33, JetBrains runtime version 17.0.6

Any help is much appreciated!
Ellen

Comment: FIXED BY DELETEING THE PACKAGE flutter_typehead
After a lot of proding, ChatGPT gave me this and it fixed it. 
One solution to fix the keyboard package error in Flutter is to delete the package `flutter_keyboard_visibility` manually, remove the `pubspec.lock` file from your project, and then run `pub get`. You don't need `flutter_keyboard_visibility` to be in your `pubspec.yaml` file since `flutter_typehead` will install it automatically ¹.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from missing files in your Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/ folder.
To keep using flutter_typehead & flutter_keyboard_visibility just delete the android-31 folder and run your flutter project.
It will re-install it and fix the bug.